# How to make dialog larger without using absolute values?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialog

I have an activity that I want to appear as a dialog and not a separate screen. When I do so, it gets squished as small as possible. I would expect something between the two images below.
Is there a way to have the dialog fill a certain percentage of the screen? I'd prefer to stay away from defining static/absolute values for sizing things. As far as I can guess, the layout is trying to match parent, but the dialog is trying to wrap contents, which results in this small dialog.

[image] [image]

EDIT: Here's the XML for the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:context=".EditPlayerActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Player name"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/playerNameEntry"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter player's name"
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/playerNameEntry"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/playerNameEntry" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="cancelEdit"
    android:text="Cancel"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/saveButton"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorScroll" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="saveEdit"
    android:text="Save"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cancelButton"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cancelButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/cancelButton" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/colorScroll"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/colorScrollContents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="right"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="371dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using linearlayout as root view?

Comment: post xml code ..

Comment: I'm using ConstraintLayout. XML posted.

Answer (score 0):

you make an use of `windowmanager`

```
dialog = new Dialog //declaration
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

wlp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);//full screen
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I could be misunderstanding, but I can get this to work as far as using the layout, but I am trying to show the actual activity, which is already coded in a separate java file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I replaced the `LinearLayout` parent of the DialogFragment with `RelativeLayout` and everything worked perfectly.

Comment: I still have much to learn. I don't know anything about "fragments" yet other than that they exist. I'm using a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Try replacing the ConstraintLayout with RelativeLayout.